# echo spesific title get_the_title

Tags: table, get-the-title

I have two title

- QCM
- Rare

I want to show the title into table header

```
foreach($quiz_ids as $quiz_id){
  echo '<th><a href="'.get_permalink($quiz_id).'" target="_blank">
  '.get_the_title($quiz_id).'</a></th>';
                                          }
```

It' show all title as title column, how to modified get_the_title to only echo QCM title

Answer (score -1):

you can use `the_title($quiz)` instead of `get_the_title()`

Put  this code

```
foreach($quiz_ids as $quiz_id){
  echo '<th><a href="'.get_permalink($quiz_id).'" target="_blank">
  '.the_title($quiz_id).'</a></th>';
}
```

Hope this will help you